# Construct a perpendicular to a given line from a point not on the line in only three steps

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

The common compass and straight-edge construction of a perpendicular to a line $\ell$ from a given point $P$ takes $4$ steps:

$\hspace{10pt}$ $1$. Draw a circle centered at $P$. it will cross $\ell$ at $2$ points.
$\hspace{10pt}$ $2$. From the first intersection point $A$, draw a circle with radius
$\overline{AP}$.
$\hspace{10pt}$ $3$. From the second intersection point $B$, draw a circle with radius
$\overline{AB}$.
$\hspace{10pt}$ $4$. Draw a line from $P$ to the new intersection point between the
previous two circles, it will be the desired perpendicular.

This method can be clearly seen in this diagram:

[image]

However, my professor told me there was a way to this in only **three** steps! I have been trying to figure out for a long time and am beginning to think he is tricking us. I can't find anything online about this supposed $3$ step solution. Does it exist and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently drawing a circular arc   is a step

Pick a point on the line, call it $A.$  Around $A$   draw the circle that passes through $P.$

Pick a second point on the line, call it $B.$  Around $B$   draw the circle that passes through $P.$

THe two circles intersect in $P$   and at a second point $P'$ off the line  and the line through $PP'$  is perpendicular to the original line

Here the point $P$   is on the graph paper at $(4,3) $

[image]

Comment: This is quite clever! Thanks Will!